# Downloading big files and passing them back to the client in chunks

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

**The background:**

I have a Java Spring boot application.

I would like to have an API endpoint where the user can request to download a file.

The file is generated by the application and stored in some remote storage (S3 for example), prior to the download request

The customer does not have an access to the remote storage.

He sends a request to the application and as far as he is concerned the file is coming from the application.

The file downloaded can be very big.

**The question**

Is there a way to have the application be used as some sort of a tunnel?

Meaning - the application gets a request, start downloading the file chunk by chunk, and every downloaded chunk is also returned to the client.

This will create a similar experience to downloading from S3 itself and does not force the application to save the file locally or upload the whole thing into its memory

Comment: Sending the client a presigned (temporary) URL to download the file directly from S3 is not an option?

Comment: @Maurice - this will require me to have a public S3 bucket, won't it? sounds like a bad idea, when it stores customer information. Better to go through the app.

Comment: No, the bucket won't have to be public. The presigned URL allows you to download one specific object for a period of time.